# How can I optimize my for loop in order to be able to run it on a 320000 lines DataFrame table?

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I think I have a problem with time calculation.

I want to run this code on a DataFrame of 320 000 lines, 6 columns:

```
index_data = data["clubid"].index.tolist()

for i in index_data:
    for j in index_data:
        if data["clubid"][i] == data["clubid"][j]:
            if data["win_bool"][i] == 1:
                if (data["startdate"][i] >= data["startdate"][j]) & (
                    data["win_bool"][j] == 1
                ):
                    NW_tot[i] += 1
            else:
                if (data["startdate"][i] >= data["startdate"][j]) & (
                    data["win_bool"][j] == 0
                ):
                    NL_tot[i] += 1
```

The objective is to determine the number of wins and the number of losses from a given match taking into account the previous match, this for every clubid.

The problem is, I don't get an error, but I never obtain any results either.
When I tried with a smaller DataFrame ( data[0:1000] ) I got a result in 13 seconds. This is why I think it's a time calculation problem.

I also tried to first use a groupby("clubid"), then do my for loop into every group but I drowned myself.

Something else that bothers me, I have at least 2 lines with the exact same date/hour, because I have at least two identical dates for 1 match. Because of this I can't put the date in index.

Could you help me with these issues, please?

Comment: It seems that you can avoid to have two nested loops. The idea of using `groupby` is ok since you only operate intra-groups. It is also not clear to me why you are checking that the date of i is later than j: can't you achieve your result by simply summing the vector `win_bool` for the win and its negation for losses?

Comment: Optimization is already adopted in pandas and numpy through vectorization, this is definitely a bad practice to iterate over data like this. You should use proper methods to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment above, I think you can simply sum the vector of `win_bool` by group. If the dates are sorted this should be equivalent to your loop, correct?

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({
    "win_bool":[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    "clubid":  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    "date"  :  [1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "othercol":["a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"]
    })


temp = dat[["clubid", "win_bool"]].groupby("clubid")
NW_tot = temp.sum()
NL_tot = temp.count()
NL_tot = NL_tot["win_bool"] - NW_tot["win_bool"]
```

If you have duplicate dates that inflate the counts, you could first drop duplicates by dates (within groups):

```
# drop duplicate dates
temp = dat.drop_duplicates(["clubid", "date"])[["clubid", "win_bool"]].groupby("clubid")
```

Comment: Thank you ! 
In your solution : 
`NL_tot = temp.count()` is an int() and because of this I can't merge NW_tot and NL_tot properly. 

In order to solve this, I create a list ( Nmatch_tot with the total number of match for every clubid.
I put NW_tot and Nmatch_tot in the same data frame, and then did NL_tot = Nmatch_tot - NW_tot. 

And finaly I used join() to merge this DF in my initial DF. 
So now I have my initial DF with NW_tot and NL_tot for every team. 

but I still have not taken into account the "startdate", so as to count the matches won or lost only before this "startdate".

Comment: First I will try to sort startdate into every groupby("clubid") with the DF obtain just before.

Comment: If you want to set a specific `startdate` you could first drop entries before the startdate and then sum as in the code above. Otherwise, if you want a cumulative sum of the matches, you could look at `pandas.DataFrame.cumsum` rather than `sum`